# Weather API not working

Tags: javascript

Why am i not getting any data back from the weather api i am trying to update the html tag to show the temperature please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loc = [];
  console.log(loc);
  $.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io?token=97f4f0d67b28dc", function(response) {
    loc = response.loc.split(",");
     

    document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML =
      response.city + "," + response.country;
  });
  $.getJSON(
    "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" +
      loc[0] +
      "&lon=" +
      loc[1],
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.getElementById("Temperature").innerHTML = data.main.temp;
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you getting valid values for `loc[0]` and `loc[1]`?

Answer (score 4):

It's because when you are calling the second request, the first isn't finished yet, so the `lat` `long` values are `undefined`.

You need to put your second request inside first like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loc = [];
  $.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io?token=97f4f0d67b28dc", function(response) {
    loc = response.loc.split(",");
    console.log(Number(loc[0]));
     

    document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML =
      response.city + "," + response.country;
      
      $.getJSON(
    "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" +
      loc[0] +
      "&lon=" +
      loc[1],
      function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.getElementById("Temperature").innerHTML = data.main.temp;
    }
  );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Location"></div>
<div id="Temperature"></div>
```